# Installing scikit-image with pip issues with Python3.5

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

I am trying to install scikit-image via pip, which is resulting in my pip (8.1) outputting :

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Beginning with Matplotlib 3.1, Python 3.6 or above is required.

This may be due to an out of date pip.

Make sure you have pip >= 9.0.1.
```

So, I run `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Then I try to run `pip3 install --upgrade scikit-image`

And it results in :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I tried rolling back with :

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```

and running :

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

which results in an install of pip v8.1.1

```
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

which then results in the top error message again if I try `pip3 install scikit-image` - stating that I need pip >=9.0.1.

Is it possible to get scikit-image with python3.5 ?

Comment: Did you try just getting a newer, but not the newest version of pip? Something like `pip3 install --upgrade pip==9.0.1`